# Azure File - Download from my Node application hosted on Azure not working

Tags: node.js, azure-storage, azure-sdk

I have a nodejs application hosted on Azure App Services and also a couple of files on Azure Files.
I made the connection using azure-storage but when I try to download the files it doesn't work.
I am using the following function:

```
app.get('/download/:name', async (req, res) => {
    var option = new Object();
    option.disableContentMD5Validation = true;
    option.maximumExecutionTimeInMs = 20 * 60000;
    option.timeoutIntervalInMs = 20 * 6000;

    fileService.getFileToStream(shareName, directoryName, req.params.name, fs.createWriteStream(req.params.name), option, async function(error, result, response) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log("result");
        console.log(result);
        console.log("response");
        console.log('result ' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
      }
  });
});
```

I don't get any errors and on my server console it appears the console.logs:
result

```
FileResult {share: 'myfileshare',directory: '',name: 'magic_quadrant_for_enterpris_361584.pdf',metadata: { type: 'pdf' },etag: '"0x8D7A037BFF0B68F"',lastModified: 'Thu, 23 Jan 2020 19:09:20 GMT',requestId: 'd7ac8a85-201a-0010-8034-d55536000000',serverEncrypted: 'true',contentLength: '278303',contentSettings: { contentType: 'application/octet-stream' } }responseresult {"share": "myfileshare","directory": "","name": "magic_quadrant_for_enterpris_361584.pdf","metadata": {"type": "pdf"},"etag": "\"0x8D7A037BFF0B68F\"","lastModified": "Thu, 23 Jan 2020 19:09:20 GMT","requestId": "d7ac8a85-201a-0010-8034-d55536000000","serverEncrypted": "true","contentLength": "278303","contentSettings": {"contentType": "application/octet-stream"}}
```

I get the result printed but no file is being downloaded through my browser...
Any insights on this?

Comment: `createWriteStream` doesn't download any file it will create and write date to file (if you want to append use `{flags:'a'}` in `createWriteStream`). So you might need to give proper path with proper extension in order for `createWriteStream` to work.

Comment: Hi @ShivamSood! Thanks for your reply. I added the {flags: 'a'} to createWriteStream and on my logs and the path is going as path: 'magic_quadrant_for_enterpris_361584.pdf'... Still no luck downloading the file.

Comment: If you `console.log(response.file)` do you get anything?

Comment: I changed it.. instead of downloading from FileShare, I put everyhing in a blob container and made it public.. it worked.

Comment: @LuanaMayaraFernandes If your issue has been resolved, could you please post your answer?

Answer (score 0):

According to your code in your post, I see you were using Azure Legacy Storage SDK for Node ([azure-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage) as the figure below) and [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) to develop an API for downloading a file from Azure File Storage.

[image]

However, the legacy of Azure Storage SDK for Node does not support async and promise features. So I think your issue was caused by the incorrect usage of Azure Storage SDK.

Here is my sample code which works fine, and I installed the necessary node packages via `npm i azure-storage` and `npm i express`.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

var azure = require('azure-storage');

var accountName = '<your account name>';
var accountKey = '<your account key>';

var fileService = azure.createFileService(accountName, accountKey);
var shareName = '<your share name, such as `test`>';
var directoryName = '';  // For my testing, it's none.

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

app.get('/download/:name', (req, res) => {
    var fileName = req.params.name;

    var option = new Object();
    option.disableContentMD5Validation = true;
    option.maximumExecutionTimeInMs = 20 * 60000;
    option.timeoutIntervalInMs = 20 * 6000;

    fileService.getFileToStream(shareName, directoryName, fileName, res, option, function(error, result, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log("result");
            console.log(result);
            console.log("response");
            console.log('result ' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
        }
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

I post a file named `test.json` via Azure Storage Explorer for testing, its content is very simple.

[image]

When I tried to access its url `http://localhost:3000/download/test.json`, I got the result successfully in browser.

[image]

And my backend logs as below.

```
Example app listening on port 3000!
result
FileResult {
  share: 'test',
  directory: '',
  name: 'test.json',
  metadata: {},
  etag: '"0x8D7A40B375873CE"',
  lastModified: 'Tue, 28 Jan 2020 16:00:37 GMT',
  requestId: 'b5bf6198-e01a-0051-34f4-d53847000000',
  serverEncrypted: 'true',
  contentLength: '49'
}
response
result {
    "share": "test",
    "directory": "",
    "name": "test.json",
    "metadata": {},
    "etag": "\"0x8D7A40B375873CE\"",
    "lastModified": "Tue, 28 Jan 2020 16:00:37 GMT",
    "requestId": "b5bf6198-e01a-0051-34f4-d53847000000",
    "serverEncrypted": "true",
    "contentLength": "49"
}
```